# Where to put one-time set up code in Clojure / Luminus web app?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, luminus

In a simple web app I want to create a few CouchDB design documents if they don't exist before user interaction starts. I understand that if I was using a SQL database then I'd use migrations and `lein migrate` or similar to achieve this effect.

However, here I will be using the `couch` library co create the design documents with JSON, like this:

`{
   "_id": "_design/pages",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
       "by_tag": {
           "map": "function(doc) {\n  if ('tags' in doc) {\n    doc.tags.forEach( function(tag) {\n      emit(tag, doc._id );\n    });\n  }\n}\t\n"
       }
   }
}`

I've tried creating an `init` function in `handler.clj` and `core.clj` (as suggested by various Clojure books) but this is never called.

Where do I put this code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've got working...

Add a new module for database setup and some functions to create the views:

```
(ns clojure-wiki.models.setup
  (:require [com.ashafa.clutch :as couch]
            [clojure-wiki.models.db :as db]))


(defn create-page-views []
  (db/with-db
    (couch/save-view "pages" (couch/view-server-fns
                               :javascript
                               {:by_tag {:map
"function(doc) {
  if ('tags' in doc) {
    doc.tags.forEach( function(tag) {
      emit(tag, doc._id );
    });
  }
}"
                                         }
                                :by_word {:map
"function(doc) {
  const stopwords = ['and', 'the'];
  var freq = {};
  ((doc._id + \" \" + doc.tags + \" \" + doc.content).toLowerCase().match(/\\w+/g)).forEach(function(word) {
    if (word.length >= 3 && stopwords.indexOf(word) == -1) {
      freq[word] = (freq[word] || 0) +1;
    }
  });
  Object.keys(freq).forEach(function(word) {
    emit(word, {count: freq[word]});
  });
}"
                                          }}))))

(defn setup-db []
  (create-page-views))
```

Add a task alias to `project.clj`:

```
:aliases
  {"setup-db" ["run" "-m" "clojure-wiki.models.setup/setup-db"]}
```

Now I can run this as a one off task:

```
lein setup-db
```